# What is the comultiplication of a matrix frobenius algebra?

Tags: frobenius-algebras, matrices

One of the easiest examples I can think of for frobenius algebras is a plain ol' matrix algebra with tr : V → k as the co-unit (or equivalently, tr(a⋅b) as the frobenius form). This is enough data to generate a comultiplication δ : V → V ⊗ V. This turns out to be μ<sup>†</sup>, for multiplication μ. Is there any intuition for what this map does (aside from the obvious "do multiplication on the dual space")?

Comment: I don't quite see why you aren't happy with the intuition that you give. It seems to me that it cleanly describes what the comultiplication is and how it arises.

Comment: Maybe this is all there really is to say about this co-multiply. I was just wondering if there's something else there, like this example: Define a frobenius algebra on any FD vector space by making comultiply "copy" a basis. delta :: |i> |-> |ii> and counit "delete" a basis. epsilon :: |i> |-> 1. Mult. and unit are just the daggers. For delta_X defined on the eigenvectors of Pauli X (|+>, |->), it's a (happily coincidental?) fact that the induced multiply delta^dag is actually logical XOR on the Pauli Z basis (|0>, |1>).

Comment: Incidentally, your proscription for defining a frobenius algebra on a finite-dimensional vector space requires a basis.  Otherwise your comultiplication and counit are not linear.

Comment: That's the point! In fact, this type of frobenius algebra (called special FA) uniquely picks out a basis in the underlying object. We often take this as a pure categorical way to define basis. See eg Coecke et al's "Bases" paper. 

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I live to think about matrices.  Penrose (1971) figured out that you can draw linear algebra diagrammatically.  A picture in the Penrose notation is a directed labeled graph with external leaves.  The edges are labeled by vector spaces (changing the direction on an edge has the same effect as swapping the label *X* with the dual vector space *X**), and vertices by multilinear maps.  In this way, placing two edges next to each other is the tensor product.  The ground field **R** should be drawn as an invisible edge, so that *X* ⊗ **R** = *X*.

So, pick your favorite finite-dimensional vector space *X*, and think about the types of diagrams you can draw using just it.  Well, the space of matrices (what you call *V*) is *X* ⊗ *X**, so it looks like two parallel lines pointed in opposite directions.  Then you can check that the trace is the directed cap, the identity element (thought of as a map **R** → *V*) is the directed cup, and multiplication and comultiplication are both given by trivalent vertices.

In ASCII (ignore the weird coloring):

```
       |            |                        | |
       |            |                        | |
 X  =  ^ ,   X*  =  v ,  R = [empty],  V  =  ^ v
       |            |                        | |
       |            |                        | |


          ->-            |     |
         /   \           ^     v
 Tr  =  |     |    I  =  |     |
        ^     v           \   /
        |     |            -<-


            | |                  | |   | |
            ^ v                  ^ v   ^ v
            | |                  | |   | |
 mu  =     / _ \       delta  =   \ \_/ /
          / / \ \                  \   /
         | |   | |                  | |
         ^ v   ^ v                  ^ v
         | |   | |                  | |
```

Not only does the notation "explain" the comultiplication, it "proves" all the associativity and unital properties you might want.  Mostly, though, I think it makes it totally clear what the Frobenius pairing (a,b) → Tr(ab) is doing.  It's just the map:

```
              ->-
             / _ \ 
 pair =     / / \ \ 
           | |   | | 
           ^ v   ^ v 
           | |   | |
```

Which is just the canonical fact that (*X* ⊗ *X**)* = *X* ⊗ *X**.  This ability to rotate *X* ⊗ *X** is why δ = μ*.

Comment: This is a good way of thinking about these things! Also, it justifies the existence of what I previously thought was a cute but somewhat pointless construction of turning a compact structure (cap and cup) into a frobenius algebra. This is exactly the matrix frobenius algebra, when you think of linear maps as their "names". I.e. express M as "[M] := (1 (x) M) o cup". The frobenius multiplication "mu ([M] (x) [N])" reduces by compact structure "string pulling" to [MN]. Cool! Defining trace as cap also unifies the "internal" notion of trace of a matrix with the "self-loop" one: Tr(M) = cap[M].